# How to edit the hoverinfo/hoverformat in plotly-python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter, plotly-python

Take this code of a simple plotly plot. I want to modify the highlighted area and populate it based on another array (let it be `q`) (or have both the original value and `q` displayed). How can I do that?

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [2, 4, 6, 4, 2]
y2 = [5, 3, 1, 3, 5]
y3 = [3, 6, 9, 6, 3]
q = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=x, 
                    y=y1, 
                    name='Trace 1',
                    hovertemplate='Trace 1: %{y}<extra></extra>')

trace2 = go.Scatter(x=x, 
                    y=y2, 
                    name='Trace 2',
                    hovertemplate='Trace 2: %{y}<extra></extra>')

trace3 = go.Scatter(x=x, 
                    y=y3, 
                    name='Trace 3',
                    hovertemplate='Trace 3: %{y}<extra></extra>')

traces = [trace1, trace2, trace3]

layout = go.Layout(hovermode='x unified')

fig = go.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout)

widget = go.FigureWidget(fig)
widget
```

[image]

Comment: So it turns out that such a modification is not possible as of today. I have created a GitHub issue (feature request), hoping it will be available one day: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/4278